# Container-fluid adding unnecessary margin gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to design a web page.

[image]

As you can see there's a unnecessary gap between the navigation bar and the image. The image you are seeing is the **background-image of a div which is container-fluid**.

This is my **html** code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Graduate" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--Custom Stylesheets and Scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css"> </head>

<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown "> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Home<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Van Boening Sets World Record</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown "> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Tour Info<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Games Played</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">How to get your room playing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Become an event coordinator</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mission and Goals</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown "> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Rules<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Scoring</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Events<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Players<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">BTRT Members</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Rankings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Player Search</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tour Records</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Store<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">BTRT Members</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Rankings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Player Search</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tour Records</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Blog<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">BTRT Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Free Stuff</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pete's Journey</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--End of Navigation bar-->
    <div class="container-fluid landing-content">


    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my css:

```
.landing-content{
    background-image: url('../images/Pool/red_balls_stripes_pool_table_1920x1080.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Can somebody please tell how I can remove that gap?

Comment: It's the navbar margin... `.navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}`

Comment: Thankyou again :D